# Finding derivative of squrtx

Tags: derivatives

Why does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z} +\sqrt x }=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$?

Can anyone explain all steps in layman's terms for limit as $z$ approaches $x$ of $\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$ when $z= (x+h)$ and $h= (z-x)$.

Comment: do you search the first derivative of $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}
\\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} \times \frac{\sqrt{x+h}+x}{\sqrt{x+h}+x} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\sqrt{x+h})^{2}-(\sqrt{x})^{2}}{h} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+x} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
\end{align*}